# Position of a particle $s(t) = t^4-4t-1$ question

Tags: calculus

The position of a particle is given by $s(t) = t^4-4t-1$ where $s$ is in meters and $t$ is in seconds. Assume that the particle moves in a straight line from a fixed point. Find the total distance after 2 seconds.

My attempt:

We first need to see when the particle is at rest, so we know when it's traveling to the left or right.

$$v(t) = s'(t) = 0$$
$$v(t) = 4t^3 - 4 = 0$$ 
$$ t = 1$$

Now, when $t = 0$,$s(0) = -1$.

When $t=1$, $s(1) = -4$

When $t=2$, $s(2) = 7$

From the values, I can see that the particle has traveled to the left and right. Therefore:

Total Distance = $(\left |-4  \right | - \left | -1 \right |) +\left | -4 \right | + \left | 7 \right | = 14$m.

Is this the correct answer? I would appreciate some feedback.

Comment: I was inclined to $s(2)-s(0)$ ... but you are right, they want the total distance covered by the particle ... Your solution is sound.

Comment: Yeah the question is slightly ambiguous ... if they had said distance, then it would be $s(2)-s(0)$ , but they said "total" ! ... so we need to include the ground covered when it went backwards in the first second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct.

$s(0)=-1, s(1)=-4$, so $3$ metres distance has been covered for $0\leq t\leq 1$

$s(2)= 7$, so $7--4=11$ metres distance has been covered for $1\leq t\leq 2$

So the total distance covered is $14 $ metres.

Comment: Thank you. The only thing that's confusing me is that how can you have a negative distance seeing that distance is scalar?

Comment: The fact that $s(0) = -1$ and $s(1) = -4$. $-1m$ and $-4m$?

Comment: @AspiringMathlete That's referring to the displacement, i.e. $s(t)$ denotes the displacement of the particle. From that information, I then deduce the distance covered.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the help!